# 3D Touch not working on Detail ViewController in SplitViewController on iPhone

Tags: swift, ios9, uisplitviewcontroller, 3dtouch

I have a very strange problem with the peek/pop in Storyboard on the iPhone.

The setup is at the moment very simple:

- A Root Tab Bar Controller that embeds a SplitViewController and also overrides that trait collection so the SplitViewController is working on iPhone

  ```
  if let controller = theSplitController {
      let collection = UITraitCollection(traitsFromCollections: [traitCollection, UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .Regular)])
      setOverrideTraitCollection(collection, forChildViewController: controller)
  }
  ```
- The Master & Detail View Controller each have a Table View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller.

But now 3D Touch Peek and Pop only works for the Table View Controller in the Master Section of the Split View Controller not for the one in the Detail View Controller.

Someone any Ideas?

[Storyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fl2n.png)
[Sample App overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIIV1.png)